# Update JSONb value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I would like to update a JSONb value inside a PostgreSQL table, here his prototype :

```
{
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: value
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to update `key1->key2->>key3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set()` for that:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = jsonb_set(the_column, '{key1,key2}', '{"key3": "new_value"}')
where the_pk_column = 42;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/CEWF51936